# Load CF7 Form via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

i would load via ajax the content of page that have inside the shortcode of one of my form generated via CF7 Plugin.
When the content is rendered the shortcode is not processed and come print as text.
Is there anyway to force execution of shortcode in an ajax call?
Thank you,
M.

This is the js script:

```
function getcontent(postid){
    // here is where the request will happen
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',//ajax controller request
        data:{
            'action':'dch',//action invoked
            'fn':'ghcontent',//function required
            'postid':postid//if of post required
        },
        cache: false,
        async:true,
        timeout: 3000,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery("#posthome").html(data);//print the html (content)
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my php code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dch', 'ghcontent');
add_action('wp_ajax_dch', 'ghcontent');
function ghcontent(){
  $args = array('page_id' => $_REQUEST['postid']);
  query_posts($args);
  if(have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      the_content();
    endwhile;
  endif;
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do_shortcode won't work in your admin-ajax.php Instead try generating your own ajax action. Check the following answer to a similar question:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

Shortcodes are applied when the `the_content` filter runs:

```
$post = get_post( $_REQUEST['postid'] );
$return = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
echo $return;
die();
```

Comment: I had already tried both with the_content with both apply_filters function, but not work! have any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: a bit unconventional, but you could give something like `do_shortcode( get_the_content() )` a try

Comment: I've update the question with my code, maybe is the ajax call wrong ? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd use `get_post` to get the post data, updated the answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Ok maybe the problem is because i'm calling the content via ajax in homepage? There are a solutions? thanks!